# Testing NSNumber for nil in isEqual

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, nsobject

I have a custom isEqual to test for equality between objects of my class:

```
BOOL result = ([attempt.attemptId isEqualToNumber:self.attemptId] &&
        [attempt.pitcher isEqualToString:self.pitcher] &&
        [attempt.vsTeam isEqualToString:self.vsTeam] &&
        attempt.isHomeTeam == self.isHomeTeam &&
        [attempt.hitlessInnings isEqualToNumber:self.hitlessInnings] &&
```

...etc

```
return result;
```

Occasionally any of these properties might be nil. When a string is nil, equality seems to work as expected. But `isEqualToNumber` for `NSNumber` objects fails entirely:

```
[NSNull isEqualToNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1896678'
```

How can I test for nil in `isEqual` and return `YES` when both objects have nil for that property?

Comment: In this case you don't test for `nil`, you test to see if the object is actually an instance of `NSNull` instead of an `NSNumber` instance.

Comment: Your problem is that you're not calling isEqualToNumber: on an NSNumber, it's an instance of NSNull.  My recommendation is that wherever you're getting this NSNull from (parsing some JSON or something?) check your property for NSNull and change it to nil.  (eg: `if (attempt.hitlessInnings == [NSNull null]) { attempt.hitlessInnings = nil; }`  Or use rmaddy's suggestion.

Comment: Yes I'm parsing JSON - I see, so if I check for NSNull when setting the number, and set to nil when necessary, I can leave this implementation of isEqual as-is?

Comment: I wonder what other data types will default to NSNull rather than nil when I'm setting them from a JSON dictionary? Should I check all of them (sorry I know this is a little off topic)?

Comment: It does not depend on the "data type" or object. The dictionary cannot contain nil values - hence the use of NSNull in the place of any nil.

Comment: I see. It seems that my NSDictionary is being created with an empty string instead of NSNull for strings, and booleans can not be NULL so default to NO. So I guess I meant which types would I need to check for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when writing an equality method you should:

1. Check the class of the object being compared first
2. Check the local object and the compared object properties for `nil`
3. Check the local object and the compared object properties for equality

If you are being passed `NSNull` instead of `nil` then that is an error in your JSON handling and validation which needs to be fixed. You also need to check the `nil` case explicitly as `nil == nil` is true but `[nil isEqual:nil]` is false.

Comment: The root problem here is definitely the fact that the properties are holding objects of the wrong type (`NSNull` instead of `NSNumber`).

Comment: NSNull is a valid result that can be sent from JSON, you have to handle that possibility during JSON parsing - when you get back a dictionary or array from JSON conversion, you can have a nil entry which is why NSNull is used.  You have to make sure going from the dictionary to real object properties that any NSNull values are converted to nil instead.